# select from table where day difference is less than some number

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to grab all SQL entries WHERE Day difference between current date and expiration date is < than 4  days

My first approach was following:

```
$sql_i_requested = "SELECT *, (To_days(date_return)-TO_DAYS(NOW())) as daydif FROM ".$tbl_name." 
WHERE (status!='completed' AND status!='canceled') 
AND owner_id=".$owner_id." 
AND daydif < 4 
ORDER BY date_created DESC";
```

My second aproach is (according to [SQL DateDifference in a where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266643/sql-datedifference-in-a-where-clause)):

```
$sql_i_requested = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." 
WHERE (status!='completed' AND status!='canceled') 
AND owner_id=".$owner_id." 
AND date_return > DateAdd(day, -3, getdate())
ORDER BY date_created DESC";
```

Neither of them work, so how do I select FROM table WHERE day_difference between "date_return" and `now()` is less than 4 days?

**EDIT:**

changed

```
AND daydif < 4
```

to

```
AND (To_days(date_return)-TO_DAYS(NOW())) < 4
```

and now it's working. Anyway, maybe you guys could suggest other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `DATEDIFF`

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(date_return, now()) < 4
```

Comment: What's better (faster) in terms of performance? `DATEDIFF(date_return, now())` or `(To_days(date_return)-TO_DAYS(NOW()))` ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date_return, NOW()) AS dayDiff;
```

and

```
having dayDiff < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from  table
where DATEDIFF(day, present, future) < 4
```