# MySQL query with DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I am trying to build a query that will load records from and to specific date comparing 2 fields - the start_time and the end_date.

```
SELECT start_time
,end_time
,DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) AS DiffDate
FROM my_tbl
WHERE start_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND end_time <= '2015-04-28 00:00:00'
AND end_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND DiffDate < 100
LIMIT 1000;
```

Unfortunately the DiffDate returns always 0. 
The ideal scenario was to calculate the difference between start_time and end_time when inserting the end_time but the I cant make any changes on the database.
What am I doing wrong here? Even if the DiffDate was working will it considered as a good solution?

Comment: What do you want the date diff to be in? hours mins days weeks etc?

Comment: have you checked the BETWEEN operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the condition in the where clause it appears that you are trying to get data for the same date, however using the `datediff` for the same day always would result 0

```
mysql> select datediff('2015-04-27 12:00:00','2015-04-27 00:00:00') as diff ;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+

1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

You may need other means of calculation perhaps using the [**timestampdiff**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(minute ,'2015-04-27 00:00:00','2015-04-27 12:00:00') as diff ;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|  720 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also you are using alias in the where clause which is not allowed you have  to change that to having clause

```
SELECT start_time
,end_time
,timestampdiff(minute,start_time,end_time) AS DiffDate
FROM my_tbl
WHERE start_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND end_time <= '2015-04-28 00:00:00'
AND end_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
having DiffDate < 100
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the having. Is this query considered as good practise?

Comment: For small data set there would not be any performance issue however when data grows you may add indexed on `start_time` and `end_time` also `limit` without `order by` has no meaning, so you may think of ordering the data while doing limit.

Comment: What exactly do mean "add indexed on start and end time"? I am not able to make any changes on the database. Only to retrieve data

Comment: I see well `indexes` make data retrieval faster. If you do not have that privilege to do I am sure the DB admin will have and he/she would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from MS SQL I was using DATEDIFF but the solution is:

```
SELECT start_time
,end_time
,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,start_time,end_time) AS DiffDate
FROM my_tbl
WHERE start_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND end_time <= '2015-04-28 00:00:00'
AND end_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND DiffDate < 100
LIMIT 1000;
```

I would like to know if there is a better solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start_time and end_time are datetime column. So use TimeDIFF..

SELECT start_time, end_time, TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time) AS DiffDate
FROM my_tbl
WHERE start_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND end_time <= '2015-04-28 00:00:00'
AND end_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00'
AND DiffDate < 100
LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT start_time,end_time,DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) AS DiffDate
FROM my_tbl
WHERE start_time >= '2015-04-27 00:00:00' 
AND end_time between '2015-04-27 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-28 00:00:00'
AND` [for date diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266643/sql-datedifference-in-a-where-clause) `< 100
LIMIT 1000;`