# How to update timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm now having trouble with using dateadd() function. Basically I want to add 1 day to cexpireday(timestamp) if it is at least 10 days after  current day.

I have tried two ways but neither of them work

```
update card

set cexpireday = dateadd(day,1,cexpireday)

where cexpireday - current_timestamp() >= '0000-00-10 00:00:00'
```

and

```
update card

set cexpireday = date_add(cexpireday,INTERVAL 10 day )

where datediff(day,cexpireday,current_timestamp) >= 10
```

I got "dateadd does not exist" for the first and "incorrect parameter to navigate function datediff()" for the second.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
UPDATE card
SET cexpireday = DATE_ADD(cexpireday, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE cexpireday > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: Please explain why the OP should try this - what was wrong in the initial query? What did you change, and why?

Comment: why I I cannot just compare the cexpireday to current_timestamp()?

Comment: @mj3475 here you can find a detailed explanation for a similar problem, but in sql-server, with DATEDIFF() funciton used in where clause:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266643/sql-datedifference-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATE_ADD` instead of `dateadd`.
Also you need to have a look at documentation. 
This is example how to use it DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 10 DAY).
Also `DATEDIFF` expects 2 params start_date and end_date and returns number of days between 2 dates.

Comment: I get "truncated incorrect double value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' "  update card
set cexpireday = date_add(cexpireday,INTERVAL 10 day )
where cexpireday - current_timestamp() >= '0000-00-10 00:00:00'

Comment: you need to pass 2 params to datediff start_date and end_date in your case datediff(cexpireday, current_timestamp())